# How Can I Use Symfony2 Fos User Bundle with angular2

Tags: php, angular, symfony

- im building authentication with symfony and angular2.
- i have already build login through fos user bundle.
- i have build crud app link
  https://github.com/afeef1915/Angular2-Symfony3-Demo
- i have understanding of integarting service with angular2.
- i have build login system which uses JWT from example link http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/09/29/angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial
- symfony2 fos user bundles handles security param(login,logout,register).

security.xml

```
<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

<route id="fos_user_security_login" path="/login" methods="GET POST">
    <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Security:login</default>
</route>

<route id="fos_user_security_check" path="/login_check" methods="POST">
    <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Security:check</default>
</route>

<route id="fos_user_security_logout" path="/logout" methods="GET POST">
    <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Security:logout</default>
</route>
```

- i have build seperate app angular2 (front end) an symfony(backedn service provider).
- can some one help how can take help from any of symfony2 security bundle which may acts as service to authenticate users.

> here i have found link which is about laravel https://medium.com/@petehouston/develop-a-simple-api-authentication-service-with-json-web-token-using-laravel-angularjs-and-240135855ef1
>
> can some advice for authentication i also need to create webs service or i should use any of symfony security bundle.

any suggestion is most welcome.